# How to assign active skills in Wolcen?

Tags: wolcen

How can I assign active skills to skill slots?
I can't get rid of the fireball I started with.
Nor can I select skills I got from the passive skill tree.﻿

Answer (score 1):

The skills can be dragged on to the skill slots.